# Beginner at Python : Exiting inner for loop soon as completing the job

Tags: python

After finding **the first list1[k] > list2[m,0]** I want to **increase the the value of list2[m,1]**. The main thing is that after the first found value and increase of list2[m,1] I dont want to continue the inner for loop. I tried to use break at the end but it didnt work.Any suggestions?

```
 for k in range(0, rang+1):
    for m in range(0, len(dir)): # len(dir) is the row number of list2 
      if list1[k] > list2[m,0]:
        list2[m,1] += 1
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. `break` is the right thing to use.

Comment: please, show an example of list1/list2.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a ["multi-level break"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Early_exit_from_loops), a statement that can break out of two or more loops at once.

Some languages have such a thing, but Python doesn't.

But there are a few things you can do instead, in order from the usually-best solution down to don't-ever-do-this.

---

Refactor this into a function. When you `return` from a function, it breaks out of any loops you're in, all the way to the edge of the function.

---

Use a custom exception. For example, `class BreakException(Exception): pass`. Then wrap a `try:` / `except BreakException: pass` around the outer loop. Then just `raise BreakException()` to break. When you `raise` an exception, it breaks out of any loops you're in, all the way to the `except` statement.

---

Use explicit flags to keep track of what you're doing. Put `doublebreak = False` before the inner loop, and `if doublebreak: break` after the inner loop, then do `doublebreak = True; break` inside the inner loop.

---

Google for some bytecode hacks that add a way to do multi-level breaks (with some slightly ugly syntax) to the language, and build an import hook around them. (Or maybe use MacroPy instead.)

---

Google for the even uglier hacks that add `goto` support to Python; you can easily simulate labeled breaks with `goto`, and labeled breaks are usually a good substitute for multi-level breaks.

Comment: Why `class BreakException(RuntimeError)` and not simply `class BreakException(Exception)` as this is clearly not an error but a desired behaviour ?

Comment: @Ara: Good point; fixed. I originally had a long spiel about pre-2.5 exceptions, which I stripped out, but left behind the ugly workaround for no good reason… Thanks for catching it.